# Two MVC applications using ninject to the same services and repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I am setting up a n tier system and have chosen to use ninject as the IoC/Di container. As part of this application I have got two MVC front ends. One is for the end user and the other is for the Administraion and configuration. I have chose two fron ends so that views & controllers e.t.c are contained and will make thinks a little easier to manage when I get to 100+ containers.

Anyway... What I want to know is?

Can I make my startup project the Admin application and instanciate Ninject e.t.c from here then when my second MVC application is called by the user it can use the same Ninject container which has alread been instantiated?

I hope this make sense to you all.

Also as an aside, does anyone know how to use Ninject to inject the DBcontext connection string/name?

Comment: The actual application structure is still unclear. One common approach is to use MVC Areas and configure the Application_OnStart (if I remember correctly). Another approach is to create 2 separate mvc apps for admin and user respectively.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1):

You could create separate class library (called maybe SharedConfiguration?) with class

```
    public static class NinjectSharedConfiguration
    {
            public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
            {
                kernel.Bind<MyDbContext()
                .ToSelf()
                .InRequestScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "server = .;");
            }
    }
```

And make call to this method from both projects